# Why do JavaScript objects not have a toJSON() method?

Tags: javascript, json

As described at http://www.json.org/js.html, JavaScript objects can dictate how they are serialized by JSON.stringify() by implementing a toJSON() method. For an arbitrary object, this method is not defined, while numbers and strings seem to implement the method. I'm curious--why do objects not have an implementation?

EDIT: I originally mentioned that arrays have this method--they do not. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Further clarification: I'm using JavaScript as a (server-side) scripting language and experimenting with v8, tracemonkey, and rhino as interpreters. In each case, ''.toJSON is a function, while {}.toJSON is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those methods you mention were added by some JavaScript engines (AFAIK the latest versions of V8 and Tracemonkey implement them):

```
String.prototype.toJSON
Boolean.prototype.toJSON
Number.prototype.toJSON
Date.prototype.toJSON
```

Although the only standarized by the [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) Specification is the `Date.prototype.toJSON`.

Personally I think those methods aren't much useful at all, the results from `String`, `Boolean`, and `Number` are completely equivalent to calling the `valueOf` method, and the result from Date is equivalent to calling `toISOString`.

So the question was: Why native objects not have a toJSON() method?

Well, with the `JSON` Object available (Section 15.12), adding another method to the `Object.prototype` is not worth, and really I think it would be a bad idea adding it...

Comment: Actually there is a valid motivation to have toJSON() instead of using valueOf: polymorphism. If Object implements toJSON() you can just do anyObj.toJSON() and stop worrying about the object type, or if the function is defined or not.

Answer (score 8):

#### The Real Reason

While @CMS is correct, the Browser makes *have* added these, the point was missed entirely. The reason is that the **JSON Specification** calls for an optional `toJSON` method for any object which, in turn, gets called to **serialize a non-normative structure** into a normative one.

```
var O = function O() {
    this.val = 'value';
    this.toJSON = function () { return ['VALUE!']; };
};

var o = new O();
var s = JSON.stringify(o);

console.log(s);  // >> ["VALUE!"]
```

An example would be a *Set Data-Structure* whose structure is actually an object which has a `values` method. This would allow one to write `this.toJSON = values;` to provide the `JSON.stringify` method the right serialization-strategy.

So, in a nutshell, its to provide `JSON.stringify` the correct strategy for outputting alternative structures.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think its the case that Numbers, etc have default toJSON implementations.  Maybe you are using Prototype or some other framework?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

From http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json :

> Encoding
>
> Prototype’s JSON encoding slightly
>   differs from Crockford’s
>   implementation as it does not extend
>   Object.prototype. The following
>   methods are available: Number#toJSON,
>   String#toJSON, Array#toJSON,
>   Hash#toJSON, Date#toJSON and
>   Object.toJSON.

Comment: Nothing has a default toJSON implemention in the ECMAScript spec.  http://www.json.org/json2.js gives default implementations for the types Jeff lists, but these just delegate to `valueOf()`.

Comment: 31.1k rep user referencing w3schools... >:(

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard to not implement functions on arbitrary objects.

try `console.log({})` and you'll see nothing.

Answer (score -3):

I doubt this is a reason - arrays don't seem to have them either. Here's how I'd implement it:

```
Array.prototype.toJSON = Object.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause infinite recursion somewhere as JSON.stringify calls `toJSON(key)`?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({});`
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`